# Using a list to store data from a .txt file, only stores the last input (C)

Tags: c, list, pointers, visual-studio-2005, abstract-data-type

I need a way to store data from a file as well as save it on a file, it all needs to be done through a list using pointers, as the menu specifies it has to be able to delete and search for an specific person`s data within the list, my problem is, it reads the data from the file and stores it, but the show (on screen) function gets stuck on a loop showing me the data it read from the file for the last person's information(what would go on the last node before pointing to NULL), the same happens with the save (to file) function and the search (on list) and delete (from list) functions, which leads me to think it's somehow not pointing to NULL at the end of the list, I checked several times every function and their calls and couldn't find anything wrong but I'm barely a student and I really need help with this, thanks in advance (I'm sorry if I didn't format the code properly).

**This is the library I made with the functions I needed:**

```
#define EOL '\n'

struct fecha{
  int dia,mes,año;
};

struct lista{
    long cedula;
       int genero;
       char nombre[20];
       char apellido[20]; 
       char direccion[50];
       fecha f;
       lista *prox;
};

void asignar (int i,char lectura[50],lista **t){
       switch (i)
{
   case 1:
        (*t)->cedula=atol(lectura);//atol convierte string a long
       break;
   case 2:
        (*t)->genero=atoi(lectura);//atoi convierte string a int
       break;
   case 3:
        strcpy((*t)->nombre,lectura);
       break;
    case 4:
        strcpy((*t)->apellido,lectura);
        break;
    case 5:
        strcpy((*t)->direccion,lectura);
        break;
    case 6:
         (*t)->f.dia=atoi(lectura);
        break;
    case 7:
         (*t)->f.mes=atoi(lectura);
        break;
    case 8:
         (*t)->f.año=atoi(lectura);
        break;
    };
}

void insertaCab(lista **p, char path[100]){
        lista *t = new lista;//crea el nodo
        FILE *archivo;//apuntador para el archivo
        int i=1;
        char lectura[50];
        archivo = fopen(path, "r");
        if (archivo != NULL){//Si el archivo existe
            while (!feof(archivo)){//Mientras no es final de archivo
                while (i<=8){//lee 8 lineas y pasa al siguiente nodo de la lista
                 memset(lectura, 0, 50);
                  fgets(lectura,50,archivo);//Lee una linea
                   asignar(i,lectura,&t);>le pasa a asignar el contador,los datos y el apuntador de la lista
                i++;
            }i=1;
    t->prox =(*p);//T->datos->||
    (*p)=t;//P->datos->||
        }fclose(archivo);
    }
}

void muestra(lista *p){
    lista *t = p;
    while (t){
        printf("Cedula: %i\n",t->cedula);
        if (t->genero == 1) printf("Genero: Femenino\n");
        else printf("Genero: Masculino\n");
        printf("Nombre: %s\n",t->nombre);
        printf("Apellido: %s\n",t->apellido);
        printf("Direccion: %s\n",t->direccion);
        printf("Fecha de nacimiento: %i/%i/%i\n\n",t->f.dia,t->f.mes,t->f.año);

        t=t->prox;
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

int buscarlista(lista *p,long x){
lista *t=p;
while (t!= NULL ){
    if (t->cedula == x)
        return 1;
    t=t->prox;
}
return 0;
}

void eliminar(lista **p, long x){
    lista *t=(*p),*aux;
    if (t!= NULL)
        if (t->cedula == x){
            (*p)=t->prox;
            delete t;
        }
        else{
            while ((t->prox!= NULL) && (t->prox->cedula!=x))
                t=t->prox;
            if (t->prox!= NULL){
                aux=t->prox;
                t->prox=aux->prox;
                delete aux;
            }
        }
    }

void guardar(lista *p,char path[100]){
lista *t= new lista;
t=p;//apuntador auxiliar para recorrer la lista
FILE *archivo;//apuntador para el archivo
archivo = fopen(path,"a");//abre el archivo en modo append, si no existe lo crea
if(archivo !=NULL){//Si el archivo existe
 while (t){
  fprintf(archivo,"Cedula: %i\n",t->cedula);
   if (t->genero == 1) fprintf(archivo,"Genero: Femenino\n");
   else fprintf(archivo,"Genero: Masculino\n");
  fprintf(archivo,"Nombre: %s\n",t->nombre);
  fprintf(archivo,"Apellido: %s\n",t->apellido);
  fprintf(archivo,"Direccion: %s\n",t->direccion);
  fprintf(archivo,"Fecha de nacimiento: %i/%i/%i\n\n",t->f.dia,t->f.mes,t->f.año);
  t=t->prox;
    }
    fclose(archivo);
}   
}
```

**And this is my main:**

```
void main ( )
{
 lista *p=NULL;
 long x = 0;
 int op;
 char path[100]; 
 op=-1;
 while (op!=0){
    printf ("1. Agregar\n");
    printf ("2. Buscar\n");
    printf ("3. Eliminar\n");
    printf ("4. Mostrar\n");
    printf ("5. Guardar\n");
    printf ("0. Salir\n");
    scanf ("%d", &op);
    switch (op){
        case 1: printf("Introduzca la direccion del archivo:");
                 memset(path,0,100);//Inicializa dir
                  scanf("%s",path);//Lee la direccion del archivo
                   insertaCab(&p,path);//Recibe el apuntador de la lista y la direccion del archivo
                break;
        case 2: printf("Indique el numero de cedula a buscar:");
                 scanf("%d",&x);
                  if (buscarlista(p,x) == 1)printf("El numero %i se encuentra en la lista\n",x);
                  else printf("No se encuentra en la lista\n");
                break;
        case 3: printf("Indique numero de cedula a eliminar:");
                 scanf("%d",&x);
                  eliminar(&p,x);
                break;
        case 4: muestra(p);
                break;
       case 5: printf("Introduzca la direccion en donde desea guardar la lista:");
                 memset(path,0,100);
                  scanf("%s",path);
                   guardar(p,path);
                break;
    };
 }
    }
```

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such. Posting 10 comments that are actually answers is not helpful or useful to future visitors.

Comment: those are NOT answers, an answer would have indicated why the code did not do as the op wanted it to do.  All I commented were the numerous problems with the code, having nothing to do with the op's question.  I well know the difference between an answer and a comment.  Your high handed move is irresponsible and none of my comments would fix the basic problem with the code.  Kindly keep your hands off of my comments  or better yet, re-inset my commnents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I was able to solve it, I was missing the use of the `malloc` function, that's the reason as to why the list never got to NULL. The following is the fixed and working version of the function to input data into the list from the file:

```
void insertaCab(lista **p, char path[100]){
    lista *t = new lista;
     t = (struct lista *) malloc( sizeof(struct lista) ); 
    char lectura[50];
    int i=1;
    FILE *archivo = fopen(path, "r");
    if (archivo == NULL) return;
        while (fgets(lectura,50,archivo)){ 
            t = (struct lista *) malloc( sizeof(struct lista) ); 
             for (i=1; (i<=8) && (fgets(lectura,50,archivo)); i++)
              asignar(i,lectura,&t);
            if(i<=8) break;
    t->prox =(*p);
    (*p)=t;
        }
        fclose(archivo);
}
```

Comment: this line: lista *t = new lista; and the following line should be combined to : struct lista *t = (struct lista *) malloc( sizeof(struct lista) );  otherwise the code is still allocating using the 'new' keyword, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: this line: if (archivo == NULL) return; will return to the caller, with no indication of an error.  a much better line would be: if(NULL == archivo) { perror("fopen for read" ); exit(1); }

Answer (score 0):

You aren't detecting `EOF` properly. Try this:

```
void insertaCab(lista **p, char path[100]){
    char lectura[50];
    FILE *archivo; = fopen(path, "r");
    if (archivo == NULL) return;
    lista *t = new lista;
    while (fgets(lectura, 50, archivo)) {
        for (i = 1; i <= 8 && fgets(lectura, 50, archivo); i++)
           asignar(i, lectura, &t);
        if (i <= 8) break; // reached EOF before 8 lines were read.
        t->prox = *p;
        *p = t;
    }
    fclose(archivo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but there's a problem, the readings get messed up because the `fgets` on `while(fgets(lectura,50,archivo))` reads the first line from the file and so the first input for the `asignar(i,lectura,&t)` function ends up being the second line and not the first.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed that issue by adding a `\n`on the .txt file before every batch of lines, still seems to have the same issue it had at the beggining though, only storing the last batch of lines from the .txt file and (apparently) not pointing to NULL at the end.